# how can I use express code to map a route in a sails hook?

Tags: express, sails.js, hook

In express code:

```
var kue = require('kue');
var express = require('express');
var ui = require('kue-ui');
var app = express();
app.use('/api', kue.app);
app.use('/kue', ui.app);
```

I can access: `http://localhost:1337/kue` and `http://localhost:1337/api` just fine.

I tried to move this into my sails hook:

```
var kue = require('kue');
var ui = require('ui');

module.exports = function galaxyKueSyncHook(sails) {
   return {
        routes: {
           before: {
              'get /kue': ui.app,
              'get /api': kue.app
           }
        }
   };
}
```

It doesn't work.  I get a blank pages when access the same URLs.

How do properly get this to work in sails?

Additionally, I was able to get express code to work in `config/http.js` with

```
module.exports.http = {
    customMiddleware: function (app) {
       app.use(...);
```

But, I really want the function to be added in an installable hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use express like:

```js
var app = sails.hooks.http.app;
app.use('/api', kue.app);
```